# Ubercart external file download

Tags: 7, ubercart

I am using Ubercart 7.x-3.2 on Drupal 7.

I am trying to sell files on my new website using this ecommerce system.

How can my users download files from an external website when they have paid for it?

I am trying to re-direct them to the website that actually provides the files

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a couple of ideas:

1. Alter the email template to include the external link to the purchased files.
2. Create a tab on the user profile with the links of of the files on the external site.
3. Create a module to allow the default "File download" module on Ubercart to link to external files and not only to upload ones.

**Other readings:**

[Creating an E-Commerce Site Using Drupal & Ubercart](http://www.ubercart.org/docs/user/30436/ubercart_3x)

[Selling Digital Goods (Mp3's, Photos, Movies, etc)](http://www.ubercart.org/docs/user/30476/selling_digital_goods_mp3s_photos_movies_etc)